# How to Identify Phantom Gaps?

Tags: css

[Screenshot http://uploadpie.com/EKA3i](http://uploadpie.com/EKA3i)

The header element contains an  floated to the left, and a  (with the four li items) floated to the right.
Simple enough, except the  with the text "Best City Guide" is slightly out of alignment with the UL on the right side.
There is a GAP between the  bottom margin and next container element with the image....  
**Is this gap causing the nonalignment? 

What is causing the gap between the two 'containers'?**

[Here is a codepen of it](http://codepen.io/Aarondv1/pen/XKqJdK?editors=1100#0) 
(A little more comprehensive than the mandatory code snippit)

```
<header class="main-header clearfix">
        <h1 class="name"><a href="#">Best City Guide</a></h1>
        <ul class="main-nav">
            <li><a href="#">ice cream</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">donuts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">tea</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">coffee</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header><!--/.main-header-->
```

Comment: right-click the gap, "inspect element". should get you started.

Comment: the `ul` element has a margin style that makes it taller than the `h1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height of the header is determined in this case by the `<ul>` and it's child `<li>` elements, not the `<h1>` on the left.

I discovered this by using 'inspect element' from Google Chrome Dev Tools on each of the elements within the header until I found one that fill the entire height of the header, or showed margins and/or padding matching the height.

Specifically this CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 769px)
.main-nav {
    float: right;
    margin: 0.67em 0;
}
```

And for the `<li> elements`:

```
@media (min-width: 769px)
.main-nav li {
    padding: .67em 3em;
}
```